# error creating datatable from combined csv file

Tags: c#, csv, datatable

I have an winform-application which reads a csv-file and turns it into a datatable. The csv-file contains one column with headers and many columns with the actual data. Here is the function which creates the datatable:

```
public DataTable CreateDataTable(char delimiter)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    FileStream aFile = new FileStream("filepath_to_csv", FileMode.Open);
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(aFile, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
    {
        //read headers...
        string strLine = sr.ReadLine();
        string[] strArray = strLine.Split(delimiter);

        foreach (string value in strArray)
            dt.Columns.Add(value.Trim());

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

        //read data...
        while (sr.Peek() > -1)
        {
            strLine = sr.ReadLine();
            strArray = strLine.Split(delimiter);
            dt.Rows.Add(strArray);
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

This works fine. Now i have a bunch of csv-files which need to be combined to one single csv-file. So i make a new csv-file and copy the all the rows from my first csv-file into it (header-row + data-rows). For each other csv-file i just copy the data-rows in the new csv-file. When i try to read the new file, i get errors saying: `The column 'column_name' is not contained in the datatable.`

All csv-files have the same structure. When i read every csv-file separately it works fine. Why do i get these errors?

Comment: For each new CSV file you may need to add more columns into the datatable.  So when you open a new CSV you must check if the columns already exist in the datatable and if the do not then add to datatable.

Comment: You mean rows here ' and many columns with the actual data' ?  You need to position the right string into the right column in the new row, strArray needs the same number of values as the row's columns.